# InavlidProductIdentifiers in SkProductResponse In app purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

When i am using the sandbox app for the products in SkproductResponse pf In app purchase.

Always i am getting the **InvalidproductIdentifier** in **SkProductResponse** .

Can anyone solve this problem ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There could be several issues.
In my case it was because the paid contract was not set on iTunesConnect.